# JS regular expression to convert 6 digit number to dd-dd-dd

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use replace api to convert 201656 (it can be any 6 digit number) to 20-16-56

Comment: Does the string you're working on contain more than just one 6-digit number?

Comment: nope ... it's only a six digit number

Answer (score 1):

```
'201656'.replace(/(?!\d{2}$)\d{2}/g, '$&-')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will suit your needs:

```
"124578".replace(/(.{2})(?!$)/g,"$1-")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5CXJf/)